# Find the upper bound of Square of Sum in fractional form?

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, functional-inequalities

I am trying to find the upperbound of the following form,

$\frac{{{{\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {{\varepsilon _i}{a_i}} } \right)}^2}}}{{\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {{\varepsilon _i}{b_i}} } \right)}} \le \sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\left( {.......} \right)} $

Where, $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {{\varepsilon _i}}  = 1;0 \le \sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {{\varepsilon _i}{a_i}} ,\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {{\varepsilon _i}{b_i}}  \le 1;{a_i} \in R;{b_i} \in R$.

I found a lemma known as [Titu Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Rn_(n-dimensional_Euclidean_space))  (As a special Case in the link) (Titu Andreescu) which looks almost similar but $\epsilon_i$ is not present,

$\frac{{{{\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {{a_i}} } \right)}^2}}}{{\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {{b_i}} } \right)}} \le \sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{{{a_i}^2}}{{{b_i}}}} $

Any hints or theorem will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Are the $\epsilon_i b_i$ terms non-negative? If so Cauchy Schwarz inequality (which you refer to as Titu's lemma) can help, the other conditions don't matter.

Comment: Yes. @Macavity. So can I write the following using the theorem directly such as $\frac{{{{\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {{\varepsilon _i}{a_i}} } \right)}^2}}}{{\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {{\varepsilon _i}{b_i}} } \right)}} \le \sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {{\varepsilon _i}\frac{{{a_i}^2}}{{{b_i}}}} $?

Comment: Yes. Note you can pair any of the $\epsilon_i^2a_i^2$ with any of the $\epsilon_j b_j $ for the RHS, so using rearrangement, a tighter bound is if you keep both in the same order - say ascending. The expression may not be as simple then though.